# Absolute right in CSS

Tags: html, css

I don't know what's going one here but I want to have close button in modal on the right side like here https://monosnap.com/file/0tktkDw6m2Y1QJOi5IBinoWRgps4gR but now I have it here https://monosnap.com/file/Un7Sl3WpVGNJgc4qclfQW9aA3PEdoa

**scss**

```
.modal-close {
  background-color: transparent;
  float: right;

  &-button {
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
  }
}
```

**view.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal-destroy-bank-employee__header">
  <h4 class="modal-destroy-bank-employee__header-text text__blue">
    <%= t('.header_without_clients', bank_employee_honorific: @bank_employee.honorific, bank_employee_last_name: @bank_employee.last_name) %>
  </h4>
  <button type="button" class="close modal-preparation__close" data-dismiss="modal">
    <%= image_tag "icon_close.svg", alt: "Close icon", class: "modal-close-button"%>
  </button>
</div>
```

How to simple move it to the right like in first example?

**Edit**

```
.modal-preparation {

  &__header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid $c-gray;
    margin: 4rem 4.8rem 3.2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2.4rem;

    > h3 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }

  &__close {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

**Edit2**

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-preparation__dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content modal-content-square-border">
        <div class="modal-destroy-bank-employee__header">
  <h4 class="modal-destroy-bank-employee__header-text text__blue">
    Möchten Sie das Nutzerkonto von Herrn l;fgkjs; löschen?
  </h4>
  <button type="button" class="close modal-preparation__close" data-dismiss="modal">
    <img alt="Close icon" class="modal-close-button" src="/assets/icon_close-ff7e8f2fd84d4bb1ad3833c3a74810b0676958b9b10f42333ea1a091f8d6a712.svg">
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body modal-destroy-bank-employee__body">
  <p class="modal-destroy-bank-employee__body__text-primary">
    Die Mitarbeiterdaten werden unwiderruflich gelöscht
  </p>
  <div class="bank-employee__button-wrapper text-center">
    <a class="bank-employee__button bank-employee__button-delete bank-employee__button--modal" id="secondaryDestroyButton">
      Nutzerkonto löschen
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank-employee__button submit-btn bank-employee__button--modal " data-dismiss="modal">
      Abbrechen
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you don't have any button with modal-close-button class, only an image. And you can only align the image inside the button. If you want to have the button aligned to the right you need to use `modal-preparation__close`  class.

Comment: It'd be best for you to add a working example here.

Comment: you'd better provide a cleaner code,  `HTML` without these `ASP` (I think) tags and a pure `CSS` not `SASS`.

Comment: @cloned please check my update -  if I add `float: right` to the `&__close` nothing changed

Comment: can you instead of your .erb file put the compiled HTML code in your question? and also the necessary, compiled CSS? then we can reproduce your problem much easier.

Comment: @cloned I've no idea how to make modal in pure HTML, it's Rails code

Comment: you can inspect it in your browser and copy paste the generated HTML.

Comment: @cloned question edited, should I copy all relevant css ? it will be a nightmare to be honest

Comment: check if the duplicate linked answers your question. if not, ask a new question with relevant HTML + CSS (not SCSS, not erb). put a minimal example so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

apply **style="float:right;** to your button close

Comment: You mean `float: right` - nope it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position: absolute; right: 0` for close button.

Comment: Nope, it looks like this https://monosnap.com/file/8D9mEnMI3evEZtDzrEpwTNXjlBV7aF

Comment: So you should set the right property's value the same as the parent div's padding-left or margin-left